# Window font size is small on WSL Ubuntu 22.04.3 windows 11

Tags: fonts, gui, windows-subsystem-for-linux, gnuplot

I installed gnuplot on WSL Ubuntu 22.04.3 and created a simple plot. The font for all text is pretty small, as shown in the screenshot below.

[image: gnuplot window]

Is there a global setting for the window font to be set according to my display resolution?

Answer (score 0):

Please see the gnuplot [documentation](http://gnuplot.info/docs_5.4/Gnuplot_5_4.pdf). In a gnuplot session, use the following command to set the font type and size for the terminal:

```
set term qt font "arial, 16"
```

to set it to 16pt Arial.